# Is commenting disabled when you run out of votes?

Tags: support, comments, voting-limits

When you run out of votes do you lose the ability to comment until your vote bucket is refreshed?

Comment: Let me find out...

Comment: What does commenting have to do with votes?

Comment: @Daniel: They are not associated in this way.

Comment: What brought this question about?

Comment: I pursued the Suffrage badge (use all your votes), then I was unable to add a comment. I wasn't sure if it was a problem on my side, or that was a feature of SE.

Comment: Found out what it was. My comment was too long and I din't notice the -118 characters left under the comment box. I only noticed that the 'Add Comment' button wasn't working. Maybe I will request a more overt signal for "Comment too long".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can still comment event after you run out of votes.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Comment: [29 no less!](http://i.imgur.com/n1MXI.png) ;-)

Comment: BREAKING, I just figured out how the TOP SECRET heuristics work! Just discard punctuation, lowercase, and sum a=1, b=2, ..., n=14, o=15, ...  ;-)

Comment: @Arjan  hahaha, it looks a bit like it! :)

Comment: I now think reputation is related to the length of the display name. That explains why you needed the "other" in there too, to get over 20k. Right?

Comment: @Arjan exactly. The "other" was what pushed me > 20k under the new calculation system (which pushed me back from 22k when it was implemented)

Comment: Maybe a curly quote in Pekka's is worth more too!

Comment: @Arjan I was thinking about using `Pekka's extreme trolling account` next. Maybe the extremeness of the name plays into it, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what brought this question on...

On SO, you currently have [46 Rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699069/this-josh). This is still below the Rep threshold of 50 that you need to post comments on other users questions and answers (this info can be found in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)). However, you can always post comments on *your own* questions and answers even with a Rep of 1.

My guess is that you were able to comment on your own posts, then used up all your upvotes in a day (earning you the Suffrage badge), then tried to comment on someone elses posts and couldn't, wrongly attributing the comment restriction on your casting of votes.

But don't fret, just one more upvote and you'll be able to comment all you want!

Comment: See my comment on this question. My comment was too long, and I didn't notice.